# enter a law school; enter law school

Tags: indefinite-article

> to **enter a school/college/university** ([OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/enter))

question #1
It’s not clear that examples above mean whether (i) or (ii) below.
(i) to enter a school; to enter a college; to enter a university
(ii) to enter a school; to enter college; to enter university

Seeing this: “[Our son will be entering college next year](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/enter) (Meriam-Webster's)”, I can guess it would be (ii). But [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enter%20a%20university%2Center%20university&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Center%20a%20university%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Center%20university%3B%2Cc0) shows the possibility of (i) as well.

questions #2
(iii) enter a law school
(iv) enter law school

(iii) seems to be used [rarely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enter%20a%20law%20school%2Center%20law%20school&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Center%20a%20law%20school%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Center%20law%20school%3B%2Cc0). When there is a determiner before *school* (in this case, '*law*'), don’t we usually use ‘*a*’ before the noun phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, i. Because the 'a' has been included it is implied later. 
This makes no difference though because i and ii are used identically. The 'a' is implied even if it's not there because you're unlikely to be entering multiple schools at once (this is also the answer to your second question - iii is rarely used because it's unnecessary and clumsy). iii us a bit more formal, but in that case you're more likely to say "Enter a school of law".